# Executing powershell script on windows 10 not working

Tags: python

I have this code that i have used for a while with windows 7 to determine the version of powershell, see below. it seems it is not working with windows 10 now for some reason, yet i can drop to a command line in windows 10 fine and execute the same cmd and it reports back my pshell version

```
check_pshell_ver = Popen('powershell.exe -command "$PSVersionTable | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern "PSVersion""', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
out, err = check_pshell_ver.communicate()
check_pshell_ver_output = out.decode("utf-8").split('\n')
psversion_found = False
```

When i run it on windows10 and debug , the output in "out" is empty string ''

i'm just puzzled as to why i am not getting any sort of error/exceptions either to lead me to figure out why?

here is cmd line working fine in windows10

```
C:\Users\admin>powershell.exe -command "$PSVersionTable | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern "PSVersion""

PSVersion                      5.1.16299.194
```

Comment: You can't do shell command-line redirection with multiple executables like that in `Popen`.

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was related to win10 host being a non-persistent VDI virtual desktop. I found out some other things/items i the env on the VDI don't work as previous on win7 , not related to python. so if anyone runs in a VDI you might see weird behaviors in windows.